# PHP wrap array elements in separate arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$arr = [
    "elem-1" => [ "title" => "1", "desc" = > "" ],
    "elem-2" => [ "title" => "2", "desc" = > "" ],
    "elem-3" => [ "title" => "3", "desc" = > "" ],
    "elem-4" => [ "title" => "4", "desc" = > "" ],
]
```

First I need to change the value from `[ "title" => "1", "desc" = > "" ]` to `1` (title's value).

I did this using `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($arr, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = $value["title"];
});
```

This will replace my value correctly. Our current array now is:

```
$arr = [
    "elem-1" => "1",
    "elem-2" => "2",
    "elem-3" => "3",
    "elem-4" => "4",
]
```

Now, I need to transform each element of this array into its own subarray. I have no idea on how to do this without a `for` loop. This is the desired result:

```
$arr = [
    [ "elem-1" => "1" ],
    [ "elem-2" => "2" ],
    [ "elem-3" => "3" ],
    [ "elem-4" => "4" ],
]
```

Comment: You could create a new array and do foreach($arr as $value) { $newarray[] = array($value)} but I'm sure there's a built in function that could do that. I just don't know of it

Comment: Why can't you use a for loop?

Comment: A for loop is straightforward. Since I'm already using `array_*` functions, I figured it would be nice to have a solution like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your `array_walk` callback to produce that array.

```
array_walk($arr, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = [$key => $value["title"]];
});
```

Run the transformed array through `array_values` if you need to get rid of the string keys.

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

To offer an alternative solution you could achieve all of this with `array_map`

```
 <?php

$arr = [
    "elem-1" => [ "title" => "1", "desc" => "" ],
    "elem-2" => [ "title" => "2", "desc" => "" ],
    "elem-3" => [ "title" => "3", "desc" => "" ],
    "elem-4" => [ "title" => "4", "desc" => "" ],
];



function convertToArray($key,$elem){
   return [$key => $elem['title']];
}

$arr = array_map("convertToArray", array_keys($arr), $arr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

outputs

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [elem-1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [elem-2] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [elem-3] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [elem-4] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: I was wondering why you deleted it. I was going to suggest the same thing as an alternative.

Comment: I realised my first iteration had the wrong output so originally I was just going to delete the whole thing bearing in mind you'd already provided a selected answer. But it was a simple enough fix so I reinstated it just so others could see alternative methods afterall thats how we all learn right?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to use `array_walk()` and modify by reference because the final result needs to have completely new keys on both levels.  In other words, the output structure is completely different from the input and there are no salvageable/mutable parts.  Mopping up the modified array with `array_values()` only adds to the time complexity cost.

`array_map()` has to bear a cost to time complexity too because `array_keys()` must be passed in as an additional parameter.

If you want to use `array_walk()`, use `use()` to modify the result array.  This will allow you to enjoy the lowest possible time complexity.

More concise than `array_walk()` and cleaner to read, I  would probably use a classic `foreach()` in my own project.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vBi9H))

```
$result = [];
array_walk(
    $arr,
    function($row, $key) use(&$result) {
        $result[] = [$key => $row['title']];
    }
);
```

Or:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
    $result[] = [$key => $row['title']];
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use array_map like

```
$new_arr= array_map(function($key,$val){
return [$key => $val['title']];},array_keys($arr),$arr);
```

Comment: `array_map` doesn't get the keys by default. You need to pass them in as another array. Check out the other answer from TommyBs

Comment: Yes sure..  I forgot to add that bcoz I am typing on mobile sorry