# How to change JSON Value to Name and Value? in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have List of IDs in JSON

Here it is: https://temp.9animetv.live/api.php

it look like this

```json
 { "result": [
    548915,
    505031,
    28967,
    520928,
    441762,
    381418,
    61650,
    249457,
    535995,
    550023,
      and more.. and more.. and more..
   ]
}
```

**I want to change it to be like this**

```json
{ 
    "result": [
        {"id": 548915,}, 
        {"id": 505031,}, 
        {"id": 28967,},
        {"id": 28967,}, 
        {"id": 28967,}
      ] 
}
```

How to do that? Am using PHP

**I have Tried**

To change it to Array using **Json_decode** But still haven't figured out a way to do as I expected

Comment: Why? What will that really achieve

Comment: @RiggsFolly Am using it on third part project, and that was their Example.. I was tried to use it without formatting that way... And it ddn't work.. So am trying to format it as their example

Comment: Related: [PHP wrap array elements in separate arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51755339/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply read the json string, convert it to a PHP equivalent object using `json_decode()`
process the array of id's and create a new array which you then convert back to a JSON String

```
$j_str = file_get_contents('https://temp.9animetv.live/api.php');
$j_arr = json_decode($j_str);
$new = [];
foreach ( $j_arr->result as $occ ) {
    $new[] = ['id' => $occ];
}
echo json_encode($new, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

RESULTS

```
[
    {
        "id": 548915
    },
    {
        "id": 505031
    },
    {
        "id": 28967
    },

    . . .
```

You can skip the `, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, thats only I could easily read the output for checking